# Combining COUNTIFS and SUM Formula in a Single Excel Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to combine two excel formulas that work fine on their own. The goal of the two formulas together is to give an output of a certain keyword or phrase if they occur within a certain time frame.

=COUNTIFS('Main Sheet'!A:A,">="&Trends!C1,'Main Sheet'!A:A,"<="&Trends!A1)

=(SUM((LEN('Main Sheet'!G:G)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE('Main Sheet'!G:G,F1,"")))/LEN(F1)))

Comment: will the word in `F1` happen multiple times in one cell, or only once?

Comment: If the F1 word is only counted once per cell then a wildcarded COUNTIFS would suffice.

Comment: Better Share the screen shot, will help us to fix it in better way!!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe in combination with something else they give an output of a keyword or phrase, but not by themselves, nor together. So that's one issue.

The first one simply provides a count of how many records fit the given criteria in Trends!A1 and C1. There is nothing in the formula that will locate any particular bit of data. So fitting it into the second formula would only give that formula a quantity to work with. If eight records fit the criteria, the second formula would receive an "8" to work with. That cannot lead to identifying a record with its result. So that's an issue.

The second formula finds how many times a given set of characters ("cow" perhaps, or "55") occurs in the target column. Helpful with some third formula perhaps, but it cannot identify/locate data on its own and as for feeding the first formula, it would give it a number and that one would check to see if that number fit the criteria. So if the set of characters occured 2,746 times in column G, the counting mechanism in the first one would see it that was "enough" I guess to make its criteria on the Trends! sheet happy. "Enough", but not "too many." That does not identify/locate any particular data. So that's an issue.

Hence the difficulty in getting them to work as a single formula. They just can't unless they feed into something else.

So I guess it's SAT time, if no answer, assume whatever has to be assumed to eventually make some kind of answer possible? Perhaps they DO feed into something else. Second one's pretty clever so perhaps that something else is too clever for me to guess. It happens. How to combine them? It's actually pretty straightforward:  Replace each instance of `'Main Sheet'!G:G` in the second one with the entire first one. (Note that you cannot go the other way around as `COUNTIFS()` requires ranges not values or formulas.)

That makes the answer either, 1) They can't do what they're asked to without more formula so the process needs re-jigged and how to combine things should jjust fall into place naturally, or 2) Combine them by replacing each instance of `'Main Sheet'!G:G` with the entire first formula.