# Creating a Count of Keywords Entered Within a Date Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I previously asked a question without creating an account and received a good response from user Jeorje, but I didn't provide much detail and I wasn't able to response to their comment prior.

Because of that I decided that I would attempt a second go around with more details, examples from the sheet that I'm working with, and the ability to continue to respond to comments.

I am looking to create a system that allows the output of the number of times a keyword or phrase was included in either a paragraph of text or a document title within a date range that's able to be changed.

The formula I'm currently using to create an output in Cell D1 counting the amount of entries within the date range is:

```
=COUNTIFS('Main Sheet'!A:A,">="&Trends!C1,'Main Sheet'!A:A,"<="&Trends!A1)
```

The formula I'm currently using to create an output in Cell H2 counting the amount of entries including the keyword from Cell G2 is:

```
=(SUM((LEN('Main Sheet'!H:H)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((LOWER('Main Sheet'!H:H)),LOWER(G2),"")))/LEN(G2)))
```

I was wondering if there was a way that these two formulas could be combined to create the desired effect that I'm looking for or if there was a third formula that would be able to combine the data from these two formulas to create the desired effect. If I'm completely off base I'd like to know that as well.

Thanks so much!

**Picture of the Main Sheet**

[image]
**Picture of the Trends Sheet**

[image]

[Previous Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1522791/combining-countifs-and-sum-formula-in-a-single-excel-cell/1522823#1522823)

Comment: My question went unanswered.  Are you concerned with the number of cells the word appears or the number of times the work appears?  For example if water appeared twice in the same cell would that cell count as 2 or 1?

Comment: The number of cells the word appears in. Sorry that I didn't clarify!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do the trick:

```
==SUM(IFERROR(IF(  'Main Sheet'!A:A  >=  Trends!C1,  IF(  'Main Sheet'!A:A  <=  Trends!A1,  FIND(  G2,  'Main Sheet'!H:H  ),  NA()  ),  NA()  ),  " "  ))
```

(I put in a lot of extra spaces to make the elements of it stand out a little better. Each set is two spaces, so you can `Find and Replace` two spaces with none and all the spaces I put in will be removed easily.)

The version of the formula that I worked out (using the cells in MY test spreadsheet) worked nicely in a bunch of variations. I then put in the references from your two formulas where they belonged, replacing mine. I did not name a couple of sheets and so on to test that I did that perfectly... so if you find it fails, put a wee bit of time into making sure I copied and pasted correctly first, you know, left out a character or what-have-you.

The difficulty I had was `IF()` seems to kill the SPILL capability, for instance, it will kill the creation of a `{FALSE;FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}` string in Excel's internal workings. Or looks like that is the mechanism. Leaves you with a single cell being tested a LOT. However, as you can see, not always, and finally I found a combination that did not ruin things.

Basically, I used `FIND()` to get a {} string in Excel's working. It looks for the value you desire, "water" perhaps, and gives you the character number in the string that it begins at. So you could get "5"  or "2,184" But in a string, internally, like so: {"5";"2184"} and `COUNT()` will see them as two items, NOT five digits and therefore five items.

In any case, failures to match the date range will produce #NA errors while failures to find the search value in the search strings will produce #VALUE errors. Successes will produce the number of the character it found the first character of the search string at. So you will have a {} string of errors and numerical values that Excel presents to the `IFERROR()` function. Its output is the values, of course, for non-errors, and a space for any actual errors. You could use a set of double quotes instead (""), but I like the space because it forces the result to be regarded as text under all circumstances so it can never slip up somehow, maybe get considered to be a 0 by Excel, and counted in. `COUNT()` only likes numbers so forcing them to always be text ensures they can never add to the result.

Then `COUNT()` simply counts that string and returns the number of places that matched on all three items, the start and end dates (the date range) and the occurence of the search string in the search cells.

I do hope I got the right idea here!